# Как разбить текст склеенный из нескольких XML файлов?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, текст

На входе - склеенный из нескольких XML файлов текст. Нужно его разбить на отдельные XML файлы.

Пример файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<check>текст</check>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<check>текст</check>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>  
<check>текст</check>
```

Как это сделать, регуляркой?

Comment: А не регуляркой просто по заголовку `<?xml` не получится? ;-)

Comment: Нет - не выйдет, так как текст идет одной строкой. Здесь для наглядности я его разбил на строки.

Comment: То что текст идет 1 строкой никак не мешает его порезать на куски

Comment: Щас еще попробую разбить при помощи Split

Comment: Какой обьём? Если больше 100Мб лучше потоками делать (Stream)

Comment: оставьте одну <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>  остальные вырежьте с помощью .replace("<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>  ", "") и читайте как обычный xml

Comment: @xSx так нельзя, в корне может быть только один элемент и декларация. Стандартные парсеры будут исключениями кидаться. А если руками парсить, то можно и не вырезать ни чего.

Comment: я забыл сказать, ещё и в ноду засунуть) Оформил, как ответ первый пришедший в голову код, но думаю можно будет и лучше сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы просто не

```
public static void parse(string xml)
{
    {
        var splitted = xml.Split(
            new[] { @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?>"},
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (var item in splitted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо - так даже проще чем регуляркой.

Comment: Этот код удалит ведь сами разделители

Comment: @Андрей ну так разделители всегда можно добавить, они же одинаковые во всех файлах.

Answer (score 1):

Это не идеальный вариант, но отличная наводка на действие

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?><check>текст</check><?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?><check>текст</check><?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?><check>текст</check>");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void parse(string xml)
        {
            {
                xml=xml.Replace(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?>", "");
                xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""windows-1251""?> <root>" + xml +"</root>";
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

                string xpath = "root";
                XmlNode nodes = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

                foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes.ChildNodes)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(childrenNode.InnerText);
                } 

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е. как я и говорил, убрали все объявление xml кроме первого и все остальное засунули в ноду ROOT. Пробежался старючим методом xmlDOC т.к. не знаю какой у вас framework